# What's the difference between 注册 and 登记, both meaning "to register"?

Tags: difference

Typically I click 注册 = "register" to sign up for a new service on my phone.  However, 登记 also seems to mean "register" in a similar sense.  Searching on [Jukuu.com](http://www.jukuu.com/):

> 法律不承认未**登记**的婚姻。
> Marriage without registration is not recognized by law.
>
> 小学入学**注册**明天开始。
> Elementary school enrolment begins tomorrow.

They seem similar, but I don't think they're interchangeable.  I'm not clear on this.

**Question**: What's the difference between 注册 and 登记?

(Note: The relevant question [What are the differences between 报名，登记，挂号？](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/what-are-the-differences-between-%e6%8a%a5%e5%90%8d-%e7%99%bb%e8%ae%b0-%e6%8c%82%e5%8f%b7) doesn't cover 注册)

Answer (score 1):

注册 (register) can also mean "licensed" as in  "注册医生" (licensed doctor),  "注册执业" (licensed to practice)

We don't say 登记医生 (registered doctor) or to 登记执业 (register to practice)

When you 注册 on a system, you are officially registered/ enrolled or licensed

When you 登记 on a system, you are either officially registered/ enrolled or submitted an application